# How can geographic coordinate system such as WGS84 draw on screen?

Tags: coordinate-system, gis-principle

A Geographic Coordinate System represents coordinates on a sphere or ellipsoid.

To draw these coordinates on the screen does GIS software apply a default projection method, or does it just consider the lat/long coordinates as planar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The latitude and longitude coordinates are just treated as planar coordinates.**

Many GIS professionals refer to this colloquially as "unprojected". Some insist that *any* transformation from spherical to planar coordinates is a projection, this just happens to be an exceedingly simple one.