# How is a EPSG:4326/WGS84 data displayed on screen if it is not projected?

Tags: coordinate-system

If I understand correctly, data on a geographic reference system, such as EPSG:4326, is in a representation on the globe and it has to be projected to be represented in a plane.

So how can tools such as R or QGIS (or anything else for that matter) immediately display it?

My understanding is that it is being projected into something (Plate Carée?) for plotting, but I couldn't find any documentation that confirms it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @bloigge and @Vince!  This other question does not answer, but another one linked in the comments does.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223174/how-can-a-geographic-coordinate-system-such-as-wgs84-draw-on-the-screen